# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry" in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What does _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry" mean because I keep getting it whenever I want the entry in the 2nd window to save the text(username) in a variable.

I tried adding user_name.get().lower() in the original function the 2nd window is created but it prints nothing since the when the 2nd window opens it checks the entry before you can even type your username and press the button.

Here's the code:

```
def Logged_in():
    global User
    log_on.destroy()
    log_on.quit()
    User = user_name.get().lower()
    print(User)
#Log in window
def Log_on():
    global log_on, log_on_label, user_name_label, user_name, log_in_btn
    log_on = Tk()
    log_on.geometry('400x300')
    log_on_label = Label(log_on, text="Log In", font=("Trebuchet MS", 18, "bold"))
    log_on_label.pack()
    #Username
    user_name_label = Label(log_on, text="Username:", font=("Trebuchet MS", 15))
    user_name_label.place(x=0, y=40)
    user_name = Entry(log_on, width=25,font=("Trebuchet MS", 15))
    user_name.place(x=100, y=40)
    log_in_btn = Button(log_on, text="Let's GO!", font=("Trebuchet MS", 16), command=Logged_in)
    log_in_btn.place(x=140, y=70)
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize a doofus mistake I did. I put log_on.destroy() which destroyed the entry widget so it can't tell the username. So I just place it after it grabs the username and prints it.

Comment: If `log_on` is not the main/root window, it is better to use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`.